# Random string generation php

Tags: php, random

Below is the code for random string generation, it is working but there is some problem here which I at the moment cant figure out what happens here is that it always returns me value of length 1 ,I am expecting a random string of length 10. Also I am passing 10 as length. Kindly guide me what am I doing wrong here.

```
<?php 
function random_string($length) {
    $len = $length;
    $base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
    $max = strlen($base) - 1;
    $activatecode = '';
    mt_srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);

    while (strlen($activatecode) < $len + 1) {
        $activatecode.=$base{mt_rand(0, $max)};

        return $activatecode;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem to work fie for me.

Fix you code up a bit:

```
function random_string($length) {
 $len = $length;
 $base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
 $max = strlen($base) - 1;
 $activatecode = '';
 mt_srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);

 while (strlen($activatecode) < $len + 1) {
    $activatecode.=$base[mt_rand(0, $max)];
 }

    return $activatecode;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/gq0lqmB3

Answer (score 6):

you return from within the while, causing the while-loop to only be run once and returning the result at that point (which is only 1 character)

Move your return-line 1 down (out of the while-loop) and it should work.

Comment: /facepalm that worked lol sopme time copy pastes are worst then you think THx for answering

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement is inside of the `while` loop.

Move it outside to be after the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statement is inside of the `while` loop making it to exit the function immediately, move it to the end of the function.

Some additional remarks:

- No need for `mt_srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);` nowadays.
- Don't use `strlen`, you don't need it.
- `{}` substring syntax is outdated.

Example:

```
<?php 
function random_string($length)
{
    $length = (int) $length;
    if ($length < 1) return '';

    $base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
    $max = strlen($base) - 1;

    $string = '';    
    while ($len--)
    {
        $string .= $base[mt_rand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $string;
}    
?>
```

I suggest you add a maximum length as well, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, whats the point of multiplying microtime() * 1000000?

each time microtime() is called it will produce a different seed!